# Triage: requires editing, how picky should I be

Tags: support, triage

I started looking at the Triage queue and wonder how picky I should be with 'requires editing'. For example [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37032762/2954288) has the sentence formatting all messed up (blank before instead of after punctuation, no uppercase at the start of a sentence). Still the question can be understood and is already discussed in the comments. Should I mark this then as 'looks ok' or should I be picky and review as 'needs editing'?

Comment: My rule of thumb: If you can read it without wanting to press the edit button then it doesn't really need it.

Comment: [This FAQ question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295650/is-there-a-guide-for-the-triage-queue) should help you. The answer details each of the options and gives some advice on when to select them.

Comment: @NathanOliver If you can't understand the question at all then the question would merit closure, not "needs editing".

Comment: @Servy I know that.  The question is asking how picky to be about when something requires edited.  My assumption is they already decided it was not closeable.

Comment: I'd have flagged that one as "Requires Editing"; there are spacing issues throughout the post and some normal text ended up in their code. It's been edited since you posted this and the editor also improved the formatting of the OP's table and SQL code.